# Convert Dictionary Chart To Text Histogram

Tags: python, dictionary, text, histogram

Have a Python module that takes a text file as an argument and calculates the frequency of the lengths of words in that text file.

```
!/usr/bin/python3

import sys  
import string

def get_len(word):  
    punc = set(string.punctuation)
    clean_word = "".join(character for character in word if character not in punc)
    return len(clean_word)

try:
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file_arg:
        file_arg.read()
except IndexError:
    print('You need to provide a filename as an arguement.')
    sys.exit()

fname = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
words = fname.read().split()


word_length_count = {}

for word in words:
    word_length = get_len(word)
    if word_length in word_length_count.keys():
        word_length_count[word_length] += 1
    else:
        word_length_count[word_length] = 1

print('Length', 'Count')

for key in word_length_count.keys():
    if key > 0:    
        print("      %d    %d" % (key, word_length_count[key]))

fname.close()
```

I'm looking to convert the output to a text-based histogram but not sure where to start. Examples below:

```
Length Count  
      1    16   
      2    267  
      3    267  
      4    169  
      5    140  
      6    112  
      7    99  
      8    68  
      9    61  
      10    56  
      11    35  
      12    13  
      13    9  
      14    7  
      15    2  

  400 -|                                             
       |                                             
       |                                             
       |                                             
       |                                             
  300 -|                                             
       |                                             
       |   ******                                    
       |   ******                                    
       |   ******                                    
  200 -|   ******                                    
       |   ******                                    
       |   *********                                 
       |   ************                              
       |   ************                              
  100 -|   ***************                           
       |   ******************                        
       |   ************************                  
       |   ***************************               
       |   ******************************            
    0 -+-+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+-
       | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Comment: How did you end up with a word with a length of zero?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/curses.html). It's a python built-in library to help display fancier command line (text-based) interfaces.

Comment: @samgak Good catch. I changed the code to catch the key length of zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that returns one horizontal line of the histogram at a given height, outputting a `*` for each column if it is at or equal that height and a space otherwise:

```
def get_histogram_line(height, max_length):
    s = "";
    for i in range(0, max_length + 1):
       if word_length_count[i] >= height:
            s += "***"
       else:
            s += "   "
    return s
```

Then iterate over a range for the height values, starting at the max and then decreasing:

```
for h in range(400, 0, -20):
    print get_histogram_line(h, 15)
```

output:

```
   ******                                    
   ******                                    
   ******                                    
   ******                                    
   ******                                    
   *********                                 
   ************                              
   ************                              
   ***************                           
   ******************                        
   ************************                  
   ***************************               
   ******************************
```

Then add extra formatting for the labels etc. You can also compute the max height and the amount to step based on your data instead of hardcoding.

Comment: Awesome! Now I just have to figure out the labeling.